# Incorrect implementation of String.removeSubrange?

Tags: ios, swift, string, macos

I came across a weird behaviour with the String.removeSubrange function.
This is what the documentation says:

> Removes the characters in the given range.
>
> Parameters
>
> `bounds` The range of the elements to remove. The upper and lower bounds
>   of bounds must be valid indices of the string and not equal to the
>   string’s end index.
>
> `bounds` The range of the elements to remove. The upper and lower bounds
>   of bounds must be valid indices of the string.

The documentation already states that the range can not include the endIndex of the string, but I think that should be changed.

Lets look at an example why.
I have a string "12345" and I want to remove the first three characters which would result in "45".
The code for that is the following:

```
// Remove the characters 123
var str = "12345"
let endRemoveIndex = str.index(str.startIndex, offsetBy: 2)
str.removeSubrange(str.startIndex...endRemoveIndex)
```

So far so good I just create a closed range from the startIndex to the startIndex advanced by 2.

Lets say I want to remove the characters "345" I would expect the following code to work:

```
str = "12345"
let startRemoveIndex = endRemoveIndex
str.removeSubrange(startRemoveIndex...str.endIndex)
```

However this does not work as the documentation has already mentioned.
This results in fatalError saying

> Can't advance past endIndex

The code that works for removing the last three characters is the following:

```
// Remove the characters 345
str = "12345"
let startRemoveIndex = endRemoveIndex
str.removeSubrange(startRemoveIndex..<str.endIndex)
```

That in my opinion is syntactically incorrect, because the half range operator implies that the maximum will not be included, but in this case it is.

What do you think about that?

Comment: `str.endIndex` is a past-the-end index of the string – the index before `str.endIndex` is the index of the last character of the string.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/string/1539571-endindex): A string’s “past the end” position—that is, the position one greater than the last valid subscript argument.

Comment: @Hamish ok that makes sense now, I haven't read the documentation about the String.endIndex. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hamish pointed out that the String.endIndex is a “past the end” position which is  the position one greater than the last valid subscript argument.